# How can I change Firefox from telling me that it works better if Javascript is enabled?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, javascript

On Windows XP Professional, why does Firefox continue to show me the message that it works better if Javascript is enabled?

When I follow the directions and look in Add-ons to enable it, I find it enabled already.

EDIT: fixed Java/Javascript error.
Cannot load a picture, even if it is in clipboard or saved as a file.

Comment: 1) Is it Firefox, or web pages that show you that messages?
2) Haven't you confused Java with JavaScript? They are totally different technologies.

Comment: 1) It is Firefox. I'll try to upload a pic. 2) Thanks for the education. I'll edit my post. Plus 2 if I could.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to post the pic. Can you help?

Comment: The thing is that some pages rely on JavaScript to do various things, mainly the asynchronous processing, displaying/hiding different part of pages etc. Type `about:config` in browser URL bar and see the value of `javascript.enabled`. If it's `false`, change it to `true` (right click -> toggle).

Comment: To post the picture: http://imageshack.us/ works without JavaScript.

Comment: About:config - Javascript set to true. Re: imageshack: I can get the pic, just can't figure out how to add it to my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1394/discussion-between-xavierjazz-and-jakub-gieryluk)

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12136606/Javascript.png

Comment: Do you have *NoScript* Firefox extension?

Comment: You can create a list of addons running using this add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/extension-list-dumper/ and post it here (or to pastebin.com and link here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a message from website, not the browser. Like I said before, JS is used to do various things automatically.

In SuperUser, it is used for instance for refreshing thread contents while you browse. Browser sends asynchronous request to SU to check if some new answers were posted every few minutes, and if so, it displays a message in top of a page asking if you want to load new answers.

You can control if JavaScript is enabled/disabled by:

1. `javascript.enabled` config entry setting true/false in `about:config`
2. Via add-ons like [WebDeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)
3. Adding a button after installing [Toolbar buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons/)

and also probably other numerous add-ons.

It's strange you tell it is already enabled. Maybe some other add-ons affect the setting (most notably, NoScript).

Comment: Do not have "No Script".